# How to differentiate parameter vs declared route when routing?

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

Having the next routes:

```
Route::get('/apartment/{apartment_name}', 'ApartmentController@getApartmentByName');

Route::get('/apartment/create', [
            'uses' => 'ApartmentController@create',
            'as'   => 'apartment.create'
        ]);

Route::get('/apartment/edit', [
            'uses' => 'ApartmentController@edit',
            'as'   => 'apartment.edit',
        ]);
```

How could I make a difference between the routes
***myapp.com/apartment/create*** and ***myapp.com/apartment/beach-apartment***

I would like to search by the apartment's name with the same URI prefix (apartment/) but with this code I'm always calling the parameter route.

Answer (score 1):

It is because whatever is being called, create or edit, is being matched within the parameter one, `/apartment/{apartment_name}`, as `create` or `edit` equals to the `apartment_name`.

Just move the parameter one to the lower most line within that block.

```
Route::get('/apartment/create', [
            'uses' => 'ApartmentController@create',
            'as'   => 'apartment.create'
        ]);

Route::get('/apartment/edit', [
            'uses' => 'ApartmentController@edit',
            'as'   => 'apartment.edit',
        ]);

Route::get('/apartment/{apartment_name}', 'ApartmentController@getApartmentByName');
```

With this configuration, if the `/apartment/create` or `/apartment/edit` is not matched, then it will match `/apartment/{apartment_name}`.